# Can I have two google admob accounts for the same iOS app?

Tags: ios, admob

I have integrated google admob for my ios app. that google account gave me from the client. Now my company also need to have an account for the same admob. That means they want me to integrate google admob for my ios app that should belongs to two google accounts one belongs to the client, one belongs to my company.

Can I do this? If so how can I do this?
Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Nope, even if you have you 2 accounts you can use only one ad unit id which is unique. So Nope.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. I will answer as best I can.

You can definitely use two or more adUnitIds in an app. Eg you could have one AdView using the AdUnitId belonging to your client and one using the adUnitId belonging to your company.